# Identify date format and convert to ISO date in php

Tags: php, date

**Goal:** Convert any local date to the according ISO date

**My Approach:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/XEmnst

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime($date))";
```

**Upside:** Converts a lot of formats really well

**Downside / Problem:** Converts strings and numbers that are obviously not a date. E.g.

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime("A")) => 2012-10-29
strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime("1")) => 1970-01-01
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there a better way to identify and convert dates to ISO dates?
2. Do you know of any library / regex that is capable of do so in php?

Comment: ok. What's `1/2/3`? Feb 1, 2013? Jan 3rd, year 2? Automatic detection is all find and dandy, but you'd be also have some automatic buckets handy, for when the system chokes and barfs bits all over your app. Basically strtotime is about the best you can get, and it's still not all that great.

Comment: Maybe do some basic input validation before feeding anything and everything into strtotime() and hoping it doesn't barf?

Comment: Your `$date` variable is a black-box. Hard to answer the question.

Comment: @hakre it's a black box for me as well. it's a user imported excel or csv file. it can contain any kind of date format. I am aware that it is pretty much impossible to find a perfect solution so I am just looking for a better one than what I already have :)

Comment: not "pretty much impossible". But *actually* impossible. Sorry about that; that's just the way it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's `strtotime()` function already does a best-effort attempt at taking an arbitrary string and working out what date format it is.

I dislike this function for a number of reasons, but it does do a reasonable job of working things out, given a string of unknown date format as input.

However, even `strtotime()`'s best efforts can never be enough, because arbitrary date formats are ambiguous.

There is no way to tell whether `05-06-07` is meant to be the 5th of June 2007 or the 6th of May 2007. Or even the 7th June 2005 (yes, some people do write dates like that).

Simple plain truth: It's impossible.

If you want your dates to be reliable in any meaningfuly way, you must abandon the idea that you'll be able to accept arbitrary input formats.

[EDIT]
You say in the comments that the input is coming from a variety of Excel and CSV files.

The only hope you have is if each of those files is consistent in itself. If you know that a file from a given source will have a given input format, you can write a custom wrapper for each file type that you import, and process it for that format. This is a solution I've used myself in the past, and it does work as long as you can predict the format for the file you're processing.

However, if individual files contain unpredictable or ambiguous dates, then you are out of luck: You have an impossible task. The only way you'll avoid having bad data is to kick back to the suppliers of the files and ask them to fix their data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems will really arise when faced with dates such as 5-6-2012 when it is unclear whether you are dealing with 5th June, or 6th May and you could be taking input from European countries where DD MM YYYY is the norm.

If you are analyzing just one input field, then you might have a chance of detecting the delimeters and splitting the string up looking for what might look like a real date.

In this case the PHP function [checkdate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) might come in handy as a last ditch double check.

Be aware also that Mysql (if this is where the data is heading) is also quite lenient about what it will put into a DATE field, the delimeters, the absence of leading zeros etc.  But still, you have to get the Y  M  D order correct for it to have a chance.

I suppose the ultimate answer is to disallow free-text input for dates, but give them pickers - but of course you may not be in a position to influence the incoming date ...